# Nested Do... While Loop Rectangle PHP

Tags: php, do-while

Need to do a nested Do... While loop that shows number of rows and columns based on user input. User types in number of rows and columns in HTML form and it gets processed in the PHP page which I am stuck on. $row and $column are brought in correctly using POST method in PHP, its the do while loop I am stuck on.

[What the code should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ZRC.png)

**CODE:**

```
 <?php
        $c=1;
        $d=1;
        do 
        {
            do{
                echo 'loc(r'.($c).',c'.($d).');';
                $c++;
                } while ($c <= $column);
                 echo PHP_EOL;
                $d++;
                $c = 1;
        }while ($d <= $row)
            ?>
```

[What I am getting as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3OGI.png)

Comment: you'll have to reset the column counter for each row. Two `for` loops seem better suited.

Comment: Unfortunately for this problem in particular, the prompt says that I must use a nested do...while loop but yes I agree. Where would I reset the column counter?

Comment: So, what you are saying is ... you can't manage to switch the order of `$c` and `$d` in `echo 'loc(r'.($c).',c'.($d).');';` by yourself ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$column = 4;
$row = 3;

$c = 1;
$r = 1;

do 
{
    do {
        echo 'loc(r'.($r).',c'.($c).');';
        $c++;
    } while ($c <= $column);
        
    echo PHP_EOL;    
    $r++; 
    $c = 1; // important: reset col counter!

} while ($r <= $row);
```

Comment: Updated post to fit your code, the output is making a rectangle but the rows and columns are not counting right. I tried to switch them which seemed reasonable enough but it makes an infinite loop when I try to switch them. Also column and row are being pulled from user input, hence why I didn't declare them as 3 and 4.

Comment: You say that output should look like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ZRC.png . My code exemple do exactly what you want, sandbox: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3189de2d646534c833666d9fe02bd805838779ea 

So, can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Oops, made a mistake in the code. Yes, this works. Thank you so much.